# ValueError when rendering html report using Pandas_profiling

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I am getting the following error when running a profile report for a subset of my DataFrame.

```py
ValueError: Value '6.180529706513958' should be a ratio between 1 and 0.
```

This works:

```py
profile = ProfileReport(
    df, title="Profile Report of the January Conversion Dataset"
)
profile.to_file(Path("../../../products/jan_cvr_report.html"))

profile0 = ProfileReport(
    df[df['conversion']==0], title="Profile Report of the January Conversion==0 Dataset"
)
profile0.to_file(Path("../../../products/jan_cvr0_report.html"))
```

This does not:

```py
profile1 = ProfileReport(
    df[df['conversion']==1], title="Profile Report of the January Conversion==1 Dataset"
)
profile1.to_file(Path("../../../products/jan_cvr1_report.html"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a [closed Github issue](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/251) that had a suggestion I got to work. My details and stack trace live there.

Solution: [remove_unused_categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.remove_unused_categories.html)

```py
df1 = df[df['conversion']==1].copy(deep=True)
df1.user_id.cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)
```

After running the above, the profile report worked fine. The classes are extremely unbalanced so when subsetting to just where `conversion=1` most of the `user_ids` are not used. This also fixable by not having the `user_id` as a category. However, this could be an issue with other categories so I am sharing anyway.

Comment: So, this error seems to be a helpful way to inform you on how to make a class distribution more balanced by grouping, for example with a custom converter. In my case, I had an employment status feature with a cardinality of 9, reducing that to 'employed', 'unemployed', and 'retired' did the trick (although you lose information).

Comment: Update: encountered it again, and it got fixed by setting `duplicates=None` for categorical data as explained here: https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/pages/advanced_usage.html#configuration-shorthands - makes sense.